# Keep record based on condition in Access or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a table with many rows that is similar to the one below where each EmployeeID is repeated twice. I simply want to sum the TotalAmount column and keep one of the rows based on the content of the Adjustment column. If the content of the Adjustment cell for an employee has a 2 for one row and an 8 for the second record, then keep sum the TotalAmount and keep the row with 2. If they have 8 and 11 then keep 8. If 7 and 8 then keep 8.

[image]

The result should look as follows:

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Select EmployeeID, StartDate, Max(Adjustment), Sum(TotalAmount)
From YourTable
Group By EmployeeID, StartDate
```

But that will not return 8 for ID 3 and 4. There is no logic telling why 8 should be returned from these IDs.